# Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, smoothing

I have This Imputed DataFrame :

```
   Imputed_Df.head():


                        Atmospheric_Pressure    Global_Radiation        Net_Radiation   Precipitation   Relative_Humidity   Temperature    Wind_Direction   Wind_Speed
 Time                               
 2013-11-01 01:00:00             999.451              207.75               99.09            4.450000           39.958667         13.600000      117.231667    2.138500
 2013-11-01 05:00:00             992.760              167.77               85.16            5.746667           56.107500         11.900000      244.410000    2.313000
 2013-11-01 09:00:00             990.272              157.00               95.04            6.271000           37.113333         12.802083      297.131500    3.270350
 2013-11-01 10:00:00             998.367              191.26               82.32            4.428000           37.946500         13.800000      143.103333    2.232500
```

And What I want to do is basically Smooth All The Columns and than add the new smoothed columns to this DataFrame , so Here's How I Tried to Do It:

```
import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt


def Smoothing(Col):
  for Col in Imputed_Df.columns:
    fit = SimpleExpSmoothing(Imputed_Df[Col]).fit(smoothing_level=0.2, optimized=False)
    fcast = fit.predict(start=Imputed_Df.index.min(), end=Imputed_Df.index.max())
    return fcast



 Imputed_Df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4','col5' , 'col6' , 'col7' , 'col8']] = Imputed_Df.apply(Smoothing, axis=1)
```

But I got This Error:

```
 Columns must be same length as key
```

Any Suggestion Would Be Much Appreciated , Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** your `Smoothing Function` is `Correct`

```
print(Imputed_Df.apply(Smoothing, axis=1))
```

and check `count` of returned columns from your `df` it should match `8` as you are taking 
`Imputed_Df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4','col5' , 'col6' , 'col7' , 'col8']]`

**if output df columns counts are not 8 then try**

```
import statsmodels
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import SimpleExpSmoothing
def Smoothing(Imputed_Df):
    my_df = Imputed_Df.copy()
    for Col in Imputed_Df.columns:
        fit = SimpleExpSmoothing(Imputed_Df[Col]).fit(smoothing_level=0.2, optimized=False)
        my_df[Col] = fit.predict(start=Imputed_Df.index.min(), end=Imputed_Df.index.max())
    return my_df
```

Actually I found Time Series data is irregular.

```
Imputed_Df = Imputed_Df.resample('H').pad() ##
Imputed_Df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4','col5' , 'col6' , 'col7' , 'col8']] = Smoothing(Imputed_Df)
```

I'll prefer writing this way

```
Imputed_Df[Imputed_Df.columns + "_SES"]= Smoothing(Imputed_Df)
```

Comment: I get This Erro :   ("int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'", 'occurred at index 2013-11-01 01:00:00')

Comment: @Dimi check updates, actually your data is not correct. hourly gap are not same. I made few changes in code and now check.

Comment: I get This Error When I try To Resample The Df: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: use `Imputed_Df.index = pd.to_datetime(Imputed_df['Time'])`

Comment: it seems it already index try this   `Imputed_Df.index = pd.to_datetime(Imputed_df.index)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191355/discussion-between-dimi-and-akhilesh).

Comment: Indeed , Now Everything Works Perfectly , Thanks Again .